# python sending argument to a running process

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a flutter project called `zed`, my goal is to monitor the output of `flutter run`, as long as pressing `r`, the output will increase.

[image]

To automatically implement this workflow, my implementation is

```
import subprocess

bash_commands = f'''
cd ../zed
flutter run  --device-id web-server --web-hostname 192.168.191.6 --web-port 8352
'''

process = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
output, err= process.communicate(bash_commands.encode('utf-8'))
print(output, err)
output, _ = process.communicate('r'.encode('utf-8'))
print(output)
```

It's not working as I expected, there is nothing printed on the screen.

Comment: Does flutter have the same output if it isn't outputting to a terminal emulator?

Comment: @SargeATM yes, when I redirect the output to a file with `flutter run  --device-id web-server --web-hostname 192.168.191.6 --web-port 8352 > log.txt`, there is right content in the file

Comment: I would try using process.stdin and process.stdout instead of process.communicate and see if there is a difference.

Comment: @SargeATM I tried with `process.stdin.write(bash_commands.encode('utf-8'))
        print(process.stdout.readline())`,  there is no difference.

Comment: Sanity test by sending bash_commands = "echo give me a break please\n". I'm on my windows machine right now so all I can do is throw out ideas of what I would try.

Comment: @SargeATM In this sanity test, I execute the program in  debug mode, it stucked at `print(process.stdout.readline())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247515/discussion-between-sargeatm-and-complicatedphenomenon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use process.stdin.write() instead of process.communicate()

```
process.stdin.write(bash_commands)
process.stdin.flush()
```

##### But why you ask

> `Popen.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)`
> Interact with process:
> Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until
> **end-of-file is reached**
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

`communicate(...)` doesn't return until the pipe is closed which typically happens when the subprocess closes. Great for `ls -l` not so good for long running subprocesses.